# Getting JSON from RetrofitError object using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using the Retrofit library to do REST calls to a service I am using.

If I make an API call to my service and have a failure, the service returns a bit of JSON along with the standard HTTP error stuff.  Using the `RetrofitError` object included in the failure callback I am able to find the HTTP status code and several other things, however I am not able to retrieve the JSON that the service sends back.

For example, let's say I make a call to the API where I am trying to create a user.  If the username already exists the service will return a 400 error code along with some JSON like this:

```
{"error":"Username already in use"}
```

Because a simple 400 error code isn't specific enough I really need access to the JSON that is returned.

Does anyone know how I can get at this JSON data? I have tried looking at every field in the `RetrofitError` object and can't find it anywhere.  Is there something additional I need to be doing?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use the [getBodyAs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/1.x/retrofit/retrofit/RetrofitError.html#getBodyAs-java.lang.reflect.Type-) method of the `RetrofitError` object. It converts the response to a Java object similarly to other Retrofit conversions. First define a class that describes your JSON error response:

```
class RestError {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;
    @SerializedName("error")
    public String errorDetails;
}
```

Then use the previously mentioned method to get the object that describes the error in more detail.

```
catch(RetrofitError error) {
    if (error.getResponse() != null) {
        RestError body = (RestError) error.getBodyAs(RestError.class);
        log(body.errorDetails);
        switch (body.code) {
            case 101:
                ...
            case 102:
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Retrofit 2.0** changed the way error responses are converter. You will need to get the right converter with the [responseBodyConverter](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.html#requestBodyConverter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-) method and use it to convert the error body of the response. Barring exception handling this would be:

```
Converter<ResponseBody, RestError> converter 
    = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(RestError.class, new Annotation[0]);
RestError errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
```

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that RetrofitError#getBodyAs(...) can throw a RuntimeException if the Converter throws an IOException/ConversionException. That caused my app to crash when the server started returning unexpected XML error responses. So you might wanna write your own getBodyAs method to catch the Exceptions instead and handle the situation gracefully.

Comment: I tried using the update, and im getting an error. `Unresolved reference: retrofit` so I tried retrofit2 but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 20):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
    Log.v("failure", json.toString());
}
```

with **Retrofit 2.0**

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getMessage();
    Log.d("failure", message);
}
```

Comment: This works. Easiest to do especially if you're just debugging stuffs.

Comment: This works fine to retrieve the HTTP response body, but it's better to wrap it into a try { } catch block, as it might be cases where getResponse()/getBody is null, and this code will throw a NullPointer Exception, like for example, a non HTTP response exception such as: retrofit.RetrofitError: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Answer (score 5):

@LukaCiko answer not working now for me in retrofit 1.6.1. Here like I'm doing it now:

```
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)retrofitError.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
        //own logic for example
        ExampleHandlerError error = new Gson().fromJson(json, ExampleHandlerError.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Two-Liner with `getBodyAs` to get a JSON Object.

```
JsonObject responseAsJson = (JsonObject) retrofitError.getBodyAs(JsonElement.class);

String message = responseAsJson.get("error").getAsString(); //=> "Username already in use"
```

Confirmed working in Retrofit 1.x. Not sure what changes are required for Retrofit 2.x.

Comment: Works great on Retrofit 1.9.0. Thanks for the simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

Using this you can get the error body

```
  if (response != null && response.errorBody() != null) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
    String error =  jsonObject.getString("error");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A much neater way to do this is to create a class that can do the parsing/conversion for you, one that you can call anytime, anywhere.

```
public class ApiError {
    public String error = "An error occurred";

    public ApiError(Throwable error) {
        if (error instanceof HttpException) {
            String errorJsonString = null;
            try {
                errorJsonString = ((HttpException) 
                error).response().errorBody().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JsonElement parsedString = new 
            JsonParser().parse(errorJsonString);
            this.error = parsedString.getAsJsonObject()
                                     .get("error")
                                     .getAsString();
        } else {
            this.error = error.getMessage() != null ? error.getMessage() : this.error;
        }
    }
}
```

You can now use this anywhere, like so

```
ApiError error = new ApiError(error)
error.error
```

This is all from [this blog post](https://chunksofco.de/getting-json-body-from-retrofit-error-kotlin-6a2281875503) (which I wrote).

Answer (score 0):

So after a little more hunting I found the answer.

Here's my failure callback:

```
@Override public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    String serverError = null;
    try {
        serverError = extractServerError(retrofitError.getResponse().getBody().in());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Error converting RetrofitError server JSON", e);
    }

    if (serverError!=null) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, serverError);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_REGISTRATION_ERROR);
    intent.putExtra("ServerError", serverError);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(FamDooApplication.CONTEXT).sendBroadcastSync(intent);
}
```

And here's the method that is called to extract the server error:

```
public static String extractServerError(java.io.InputStream is) {
    String serverError = null;
    String serverErrorDescription = null;
try {

    String s = convertStreamToString(is);

    JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject(s);
    serverError = messageObject.optString("error");
    serverErrorDescription = messageObject.optString("error_description");
    if (serverErrorDescription!=null && !serverErrorDescription.equals("")) {
        return serverErrorDescription;
    } else {
        return serverError;
    }
    //String serverStack = messageObject.getString("stack");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Basemodel", "Error converting RetrofitError server JSON", e);
}

return "";
}
```

This will extract the error information sent by the service that is encoded in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I compile many answer and wrote some code to achieve something nicer :

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "Email not valid.",
            "Unable to find the user toto@toto.fr."
        ]
    }
}
```

I take all item in 'email' and display them concatained with Guava Joiner:

```
String json =  new String(((TypedByteArray)error.getResponse()
    .getBody()).getBytes());

Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(
    json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>>() {}.getType());

try {
    List<String> errorsEmail = 
        (List<String>) ((Map)map.get("errors")).get("email");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Joiner.on("\n")
        .join(errorsEmail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same. My problem was a `long` field that was coming from server as an empty `String` `""`. Retrofit was giving `NumberFormatException` because it seems like Gson doesn't convert an empty string to `long` (I'd suggest to make it 0L or something). So I had to change:

```
long errorCode;
```

to

```
String errorCode;
```

As it was said before, I had no access to the JSON message when debugging. I finally found the error using RequestMaker page, maybe it helps someone else

http://requestmaker.com/