# Retrofit 2.0 how to get deserialised error response.body

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using **Retrofit 2.0.0-beta1**.

In tests i have an alternate scenario and expect error HTTP 400

I would like to have `retrofit.Response<MyError> response`
but `response.body() == null`

MyError is not deserialised - i see it only here

```
response.errorBody().string()
```

but it doesn't give me MyError as object

Comment: its simple https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: is it a good practice to deserialise the error response? since the response might be a webserver error which is html.

Comment: thx @ahmadalibaloch, that link is really really helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by:

```java
Converter<MyError> converter = 
    (Converter<MyError>)JacksonConverterFactory.create().get(MyError.class);
MyError myError =  converter.fromBody(response.errorBody());
```

Comment: How can I convert through GsonConverterFactory ? Any idea ?

Comment: I found a way. I just change `JacksonConverterFactory ` to `GsonConverterFactory` It converts json into my custom object but it gives warning **Unchecked cast retrofit.Converter<capture<?>>**

Comment: What MyError class have?

Answer (score 219):

I currently use a very easy implementation, which does not require to use converters or special classes. The code I use is the following:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    DialogHelper.dismiss();

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        // Do your success stuff...
    } else {
        try {
            JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

A point to note here is that `response.errorBody().string()` will return the correct value only once. If you call it again, it will return an empty string. So in case you want to reuse it, store the value in a variable with the first call.

There is a way to get the error body string from the response without making it empty on the next call, by rolling your own implementation of `toString()` that does not update the `errorBody` Buffer's read-pointer.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857446/9952567) for more info.

Comment: Your solution doesn't show an error response content.

Comment: Check my edit, dunno why I made it so unclear in the first place.

Comment: Finally, a simple answer to an android question that works (most android answers are comically complex).

Comment: This is definitely not answering the question. It simply return the error message and not the Error Enum Object. Please follow this response :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103420/2914140

Comment: In the answer it's looking for a mapping to "message", but my error response didn't have that. It had a mapping to "error". So everyone reading, it depends on the response you get!

Comment: If you need to use response.errorBody().string() more than once, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857446/9952567

Comment: make sure also dont call it in the watch windows

Answer (score 103):

**ErrorResponse** is your custom response object

Kotlin

```
val gson = Gson()
val type = object : TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.type
var errorResponse: ErrorResponse? = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type)
```

Java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.getType();
ErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody.charStream(),type);
```

Comment: you shouldn't be force unwrapping optionals: `gson.fromJson(response.errorBody()?.charStream(), type)`

Answer (score 46):

I solved it by:

```
 if(!response.isSuccessful()){
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       MyErrorMessage message=gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(),MyErrorMessage.class);
       if(message.getCode()==ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_EMAIL_ID_CODE){
                  //DO Error Code specific handling                        
        }else{
                 //DO GENERAL Error Code Specific handling                               
        }
    }
```

MyErrorMessage Class:

```
  public class MyErrorMessage {
     private int code;
     private String message;

     public int getCode() {
        return code;
     }

     public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
     }

     public String getMessage() {
         return message;
     }

     public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
     }
   }
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Use `.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())` @RonelGonzales

Answer (score 40):

It's actually very straight forward.

Kotlin:

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())
responseInterface.onFailure(jsonObj.getString("msg"))
```

Java:

```
    if(response.errorBody()!=null){
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(TextStreamsKt.readText(response.errorBody().charStream()));
        responseInterface.onFailure(jsonObj.getString("msg"));
    }else{
        responseInterface.onFailure("you might want to return a generic error message.");
    }
```

Tested on retrofit:2.5.0.
Read the text from the charStream which will give you a String, then parse to JSONObject.

Adios.

Comment: there's no `readText()` extension on java, use `TextStreamsKt.readText(response.errorBody().charStream())` if you still on java

Comment: Update: Retrofit 2.6.2 -> 
                        `val errorMessage=jsonObj.getJSONArray("errors").getJSONObject(0).getString("message")`

Comment: @Wale, Why this doesn't work for body without an error? **JSONObject(response.body()!!.charStream().readText())**

Comment: @Oleksandr I'm not sure I get your question but I don't think your response.body has a byteStream function, it could come as a String if you using a scala converter or related or it could simple come as an object you passed if you're using google gson converter.
So, what you're trying to do might be this=> JSONObject (response.errorBody()!!.charStream().readText())

Comment: @TaslimOseni I'm glad it worked for you too.

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot. 

Answer (score 33):

In Retrofit 2.0 beta2 this is the way that I'm getting error responses:

1. Synchronous

   ```java
   try {
      Call<RegistrationResponse> call = backendServiceApi.register(data.in.account, data.in.password,
              data.in.email);
      Response<RegistrationResponse> response = call.execute();
      if (response != null && !response.isSuccess() && response.errorBody() != null) {
          Converter<ResponseBody, BasicResponse> errorConverter =
                  MyApplication.getRestClient().getRetrofitInstance().responseConverter(BasicResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
          BasicResponse error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
          //DO ERROR HANDLING HERE
          return;
      }
      RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = response.body();
      //DO SUCCESS HANDLING HERE
   } catch (IOException e) {
      //DO NETWORK ERROR HANDLING HERE
   }
   ```
2. Asynchronous

   ```java
   Call<BasicResponse> call = service.loadRepo();
   call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Response<BasicResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
           if (response != null && !response.isSuccess() && response.errorBody() != null) {
               Converter<ResponseBody, BasicResponse> errorConverter =
                   retrofit.responseConverter(BasicResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
               BasicResponse error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
               //DO ERROR HANDLING HERE
               return;
           }
           RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = response.body();
           //DO SUCCESS HANDLING HERE
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           //DO NETWORK ERROR HANDLING HERE
       }
   });
   ```

**Update for Retrofit 2 beta3:**

1. Synchronous - not changed
2. Asynchronous - Retrofit parameter was removed from onResponse

   ```java
   Call<BasicResponse> call = service.loadRepo();
   call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Response<BasicResponse> response) {
           if (response != null && !response.isSuccess() && response.errorBody() != null) {
               Converter<ResponseBody, BasicResponse> errorConverter =
                   MyApplication.getRestClient().getRetrofitInstance().responseConverter(BasicResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
               BasicResponse error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
               //DO ERROR HANDLING HERE
               return;
           }
           RegistrationResponse registrationResponse = response.body();
           //DO SUCCESS HANDLING HERE
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           //DO NETWORK ERROR HANDLING HERE
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: what do you have in BasicResponse ?

Comment: Just a basic Jackson annotated class that contains message and error code. In any case you can have any annotated class there that matches your server response type. Try using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate one matching your needs.

Comment: For others, you may use this instead:



Converter<ResponseBody, <Message> errorConverter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Message.class, new Annotation[0]);

Comment: @JFreeman, what if I want to deserialize `List<BasicResponse>`?

Comment: can you for me see class MyApplication

Comment: Sorry but how should look like the BasicResponse class for a JSON response?

Answer (score 29):

Create a model of the Error response & user Gson to convert the response to it. This will just work fine.

**APIError.java**

```
public class APIError {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** (inside request onResponse)

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    // Do your success stuff...

} else {
    APIError message = new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), APIError.class);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + message.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This by far is the most elegant way of doing it.. thanks for the answer...

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using errorBody().toString instead of  errorBody().charStream(). Thanks again

Answer (score 12):

If you use Kotlin another solution could be just create extension function for Response class:

```
inline fun <reified T>Response<*>.parseErrJsonResponse(): T?
{
    val moshi = MyCustomMoshiBuilder().build()
    val parser = moshi.adapter(T::class.java)
    val response = errorBody()?.string()
    if(response != null)
        try {
            return parser.fromJson(response)
        } catch(e: JsonDataException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    return null
}
```

Usage

```
val myError = response.parseErrJsonResponse<MyErrorResponse>()
if(myError != null) {
   // handle your error logic here
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Finally someone used Kotlin power to make code easy to read !

Answer (score 11):

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, retrofit2.Response<Void> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            //Do something if response is ok
            } else {

                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement mJson = null;
                try {
                    mJson = parser.parse(response.errorBody().string());
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    MyError errorResponse = gson.fromJson(mJson, MyError.class);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 10):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103420/2914140 and https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling this variant is shown for Retrofit 2.1.0.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ...
        } else {
            Converter<ResponseBody, MyError> converter
                    = MyApplication.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(
                    MyError.class, new Annotation[0]);
            MyError errorResponse = null;
            try {
                errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I was facing same issue. I solved it with retrofit. Let me show this...

If your error JSON structure are like

```
{
"error": {
    "status": "The email field is required."
}
}


My ErrorRespnce.java 

public class ErrorResponse {

   @SerializedName("error")
   @Expose
   private ErrorStatus error;

   public ErrorStatus getError() {
      return error;
   }

   public void setError(ErrorStatus error) {
      this.error = error;
   }
}
```

And this my Error status class

```
public class ErrorStatus {

  @SerializedName("status")
  @Expose
  private String status;

  public String getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status;
  }
}
```

Now we need a class which can handle our json.

```
  public class ErrorUtils {

   public static ErrorResponse parseError (Response<?> response){
      Converter<ResponseBody , ErrorResponse> converter =          ApiClient.getClient().responseBodyConverter(ErrorResponse.class , new Annotation[0]);
    ErrorResponse errorResponse;
    try{
        errorResponse = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    }catch (IOException e){
        return new ErrorResponse();
    }
    return errorResponse;
}
}
```

Now we can check our response in retrofit api call

```
private void registrationRequest(String name , String email , String password , String c_password){


    final Call<RegistrationResponce> registrationResponceCall = apiInterface.getRegistration(name , email , password , c_password);
    registrationResponceCall.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponce>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponce> call, Response<RegistrationResponce> response) {



            if (response.code() == 200){


            }else if (response.code() == 401){


                ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorUtils.parseError(response);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+errorResponse.getError().getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponce> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

That's it now you can show your Toast

Comment: App Crash
ErrorResponse$ErrorStatus.getStatus()' on a null object reference

Comment: It goes into catch block of ErrorUtils and says
 End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        if (response.errorBody() != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.errorBody().byteStream()));

            String eLine = null;
            while ((eLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                error.append(eLine);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        error.append(e.getMessage());
    }

    Log.e("Error", error.toString());
}
```

Comment: This works.. with laravel api response of 422

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me for retrofit 2.9.0

Answer (score 7):

There are many valid answers already. This is just an addition for a use case, when you need to consume same Retrofit response more than once. Neither of below can be used, as [you can read response body only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739105/how-to-get-both-a-pojo-and-the-raw-response-string-back-with-retrofit), as it will be closed afterwards and you will get `null` each next time, when you try to read from the same response object:

```
response()?.errorBody()?.charStream()?.readText()
response()?.errorBody()?.string()
```

Instead, you can get read-only copy of response string (while the response itself can be passed over and eventually consumed later):

```
response()?.errorBody()?.source()?.buffer?.snapshot()?.utf8()
```

Comment: This should be higher!

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way for asynchronous calls using Retrofit 2.0-beta2:

```java
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<RegistrationResponse> response, 
                       Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        // Do success handling here
    } else {
        try {
            MyError myError = (MyError)retrofit.responseConverter(
                    MyError.class, MyError.class.getAnnotations())
                .convert(response.errorBody());
            // Do error handling here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What will be MyError class?

Comment: I thought onResponse was supposed to contain a Call parameter and a Response parameter.  How is it that yours has a Retrofit parameter?

Comment: @MartyMiller this was done for the following version of retrofit Retrofit 2.0-beta2

Answer (score 6):

Here is elegant solution using `Kotlin` extensions:

```
data class ApiError(val code: Int, val message: String?) {
    companion object {
        val EMPTY_API_ERROR = ApiError(-1, null)
    }
}

fun Throwable.getApiError(): ApiError? {
    if (this is HttpException) {
        try {
            val errorJsonString = this.response()?.errorBody()?.string()
            return Gson().fromJson(errorJsonString, ApiError::class.java)
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
    return EMPTY_API_ERROR
}
```

and usage:

`showError(retrofitThrowable.getApiError()?.message)`

Comment: Love this.  Could also easily be made generic so that you could pass in an error type:
`fun <T:Exception> Throwable.getCustomException(classType: Class<T>): T?` then update the GSON line to `Gson().fromJson(errorJsonString, classType)`.  Used as `e.getCustomException(CustomException::class.java)?`

Answer (score 4):

json response

```
{
    "success": false,
    "status_code": 32,
    "status_message": "Email not verified: Your email address has not been verified."
}
```

Error class

```
data class ResponseError(
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    val statusCode: Int,
    @SerializedName("status_message")
    val statusMessage: String,
    @SerializedName("success")
    val success: Boolean
)
```

get error message

```
fun <T : Any> getResultOrError(response: Response<T>): T? {
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        return response.body()
    } else {
        try {
            val responseError = Gson().fromJson(
                response.errorBody()?.string(),
                ResponseError::class.java
            )
            throw Throwable(responseError.statusMessage)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw Throwable("Unknown error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This way you do not need a Retrofit instance if you only are injecting a service created from Retrofit.

```
public class ErrorUtils {

  public static APIError parseError(Context context, Response<?> response) {

    APIError error = new APIError();

    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        error = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(), APIError.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(error.getErrorMessage())) {
        error.setError(response.raw().message());
    }
    return error;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {

      ...

    } else {

      String msg = ErrorUtils.parseError(fragment.getActivity(), response).getError(); // would be from your error class
      Snackbar.make(someview, msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

if your error response is a string you can deserialize it by using the following kotlin code :

```
val errorString = response.errorBody()?.byteStream()?.bufferedReader().use { it?.readText() }  // defaults to UTF-8
```

Comment: you can simply use "response.message().toString()" which will give the same error string in a more readable format.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the problem when you use OkHttp along with Retrofit, so either you can remove OkHttp or use code below to get error body:

```
if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
 InputStream i = response.errorBody().byteStream();
 BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
 StringBuilder errorResult = new StringBuilder();
 String line;
 try {
   while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   errorResult.append(line).append('\n');
   }
 } catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested and works

```
 public BaseModel parse(Response<BaseModel> response , Retrofit retrofit){
            BaseModel error = null;
            Converter<ResponseBody, BaseModel> errorConverter =
                    retrofit.responseBodyConverter(BaseModel.class, new Annotation[0]);
            try {
                if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                    error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return error;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For people using Kotlin with Moshi and coroutines, this is what I did:

Error data class

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ApiResponseNoData(
    val exito: Int,
    val error: String?
)
```

Extension

```kotlin
fun ResponseBody.getApiError(): String? {
    return try {
        Moshi
            .Builder()
            .build()
            .adapter(ApiResponseNoData::class.java)
            .fromJson(string())
            ?.error
    }catch(e: Exception) { null }
}
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
fun test() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = repository.test()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                ...
            }else{
                val errorMsg = response.errorBody()?.getApiError() ?: "Unexpected error occurred"
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin I solved it creating a custom ResponseBody generic extension function function that converts the response body to a JSONObject. then you can use gson to customize the error response body with your custom Error Data Class.

```
inline fun <reified T> ResponseBody.getErrorObject(): T {
    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(charStream().readText())
    return gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), T::class.java)
}
```

You can then customize the error response to your custom class. For this I'm using an example

```
data class LoginError(
    val error: Error,
    val message: String,
    val success: Boolean
)

data class Error(
    val error: String,
    val status: Int
)
```

then use the extension function this way

```
val error = state.errorBody.getErrorObject<LoginError>()
```

the `state.errorBody` is my error response from retrofit of type ResponseBody

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
                ResponseBody response = ((HttpException) t).response().errorBody();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject( new String(response.bytes()) );
                errMsg = json.getString("message");
            }catch(JSONException e){
                return t.getMessage();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                return t.getMessage();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

```
val call = APIClient.getInstance().signIn(AuthRequestWrapper(AuthRequest("1234567890z", "12341234", "nonce")))
call.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthResponse> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthResponse>, response: Response<AuthResponse>) {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {

        } else {
            val a = object : Annotation{}
            val errorConverter = RentalGeekClient.getRetrofitInstance().responseBodyConverter<AuthFailureResponse>(AuthFailureResponse::class.java, arrayOf(a))
            val authFailureResponse = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody())
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthResponse>, t: Throwable) {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

errorBody values should set APIError object in Retrofit. So that, you can use the below code structure.

```
public class APIErrorUtils {

    public static APIError parseError(Response<?> response) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter = API.getClient().responseBodyConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        APIError error;

        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "****************************************************");
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** SERVICE LOG");
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** TIMESTAMP: " + String.valueOf(error.getTimestamp()));
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** STATUS: " + String.valueOf(error.getStatus()));
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** ERROR: " + error.getError());
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** MESSAGE: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "***** PATH: " + error.getPath());
            Log.d("SERVICELOG", "****************************************************");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new APIError();
        }

        return error;
    }
}

APIError error = APIErrorUtils.parseError(response);
if (error.getStatus() == 400) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val error = JSONObject(callApi.errorBody()?.string() as String)
            CustomResult.OnError(CustomNotFoundError(userMessage = error["userMessage"] as String))

open class CustomError (
    val traceId: String? = null,
    val errorCode: String? = null,
    val systemMessage: String? = null,
    val userMessage: String? = null,
    val cause: Throwable? = null
)

open class ErrorThrowable(
    private val traceId: String? = null,
    private val errorCode: String? = null,
    private val systemMessage: String? = null,
    private val userMessage: String? = null,
    override val cause: Throwable? = null
) : Throwable(userMessage, cause) {
    fun toError(): CustomError = CustomError(traceId, errorCode, systemMessage, userMessage, cause)
}


class NetworkError(traceId: String? = null, errorCode: String? = null, systemMessage: String? = null, userMessage: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null):
    CustomError(traceId, errorCode, systemMessage, userMessage?: "Usted no tiene conexión a internet, active los datos", cause)

class HttpError(traceId: String? = null, errorCode: String? = null, systemMessage: String? = null, userMessage: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null):
    CustomError(traceId, errorCode, systemMessage, userMessage, cause)

class UnknownError(traceId: String? = null, errorCode: String? = null, systemMessage: String? = null, userMessage: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null):
    CustomError(traceId, errorCode, systemMessage, userMessage?: "Unknown error", cause)

class CustomNotFoundError(traceId: String? = null, errorCode: String? = null, systemMessage: String? = null, userMessage: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null):
    CustomError(traceId, errorCode, systemMessage, userMessage?: "Data not found", cause)`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error body handling in kotlin Android**

```
catch (cause: Throwable) {
            when (cause) {
                is HttpException -> {
                    try {
                        val YourErrorResponseClassObj = Gson().fromJson(cause.response()?.errorBody()?.charStream(), YourErrorResponseClass::class.java)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    //Other errors like Network ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple. and this save my life ever

```
public static void displayApiResponseErrorBody(Response<?> response)
{
    InputStream i = response.errorBody().byteStream();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
    StringBuilder errorResult = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            errorResult.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        Log.d("API_RESPONSE_ERROR_BODY",String.valueOf(errorResult));
        System.out.println(errorResult);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of retrofit error Response, You can get body using error.getResponse(), Here is the example.

```
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error){
            if(error.getResponse().getStatus()==201){
                LogUtil.INSTANCE.debug("Success : " + error.toString());
                callback.success(error.getResponse().getBody);
            }else{
                LogUtil.INSTANCE.debug("failure: " + error.toString());
                callback.failure(error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val reader = BufferedReader(response.errorBody()?.source().inputStream().reader())
                
val content = StringBuilder()

reader.use { readerBuffer ->
    var line = readerBuffer.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        content.append(line)
        line = readerBuffer.readLine()
    }
}

Gson().fromJson(content.toString(), ResponseData::class.java)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I did this way and it worked like a charm

```
val errorBody = (response?.errorBody() as ResponseBody).string()
```