# Android. Retrofit 2 beta-4. Get error string body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I use Retrofit 2:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
```

I've added **okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor** for logging responses. And I see my logs:

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 400 Bad Request http://myurl.com/api/ (616ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 07:59:50 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.12
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding
D/OkHttp: Connection: close
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1455868788858
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1455868789211
D/OkHttp: {"error_message":"Validation error"}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (87-byte body)
```

How can I get error body string from response? In my example it is json string - {"error_message":"Validation error"}

I've tried this way:

```
import retrofit2.Response;

Reader charStream = response.raw().body().charStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(charStream);
String line = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

But I've get IllegalStateException on this line:

```
Reader charStream = response.raw().body().charStream();

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read raw response body of a converted body.
retrofit2.OkHttpCall$NoContentResponseBody.source(OkHttpCall.java:257)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.byteStream(ResponseBody.java:69)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.charStream(ResponseBody.java:100)
at com.myapp.delegate.retrofit.ApiDelegateRetrofit.parseError(ApiDelegateRetrofit.java:146)
```

**EDIT:**

I've resolved it for beta-4 (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32896077/1225669):

```
if (response != null && response.errorBody() != null) {
    Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorData> errorConverter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ErrorData.class, new Annotation[0]);
    try {
        ErrorData error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
        return error;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should use `response.errorBody()` instead of response.raw().body().
Here is more detailed explanation of Retrofit 2 erro handling [Retrofit 2.0 how to get deserialised error response.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519618/retrofit-2-0-how-to-get-deserialised-error-response-body).

Comment: Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896077/1225669. I've modified example of beta-3 to beta-4. Please see my modified question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

`response.errorBody();`

or

`response.message();`