# Retrofit 2: responseBodyConverter converts to null object

Tags: android, http, error-handling, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using the latest (as of now 2.0.0-beta4) version of [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). When receiving 200 OK code from server, everything is working fine. But I want to deal with not OK responses too, such as code 401. So, I have to get the error response code to figure out exactly what action to do and display appropriate data:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
    if (response != null && !response.isSuccess() && response.errorBody() != null) {
        Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> errorConverter = retrofit.responseBodyConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);
        try {
            APIError error = errorConverter.convert(response.errorBody());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "code = " + error.getCode() + ", status = " + error.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (null != response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successful login: " + loginResponse.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**APIError.java**

```
public class APIError {
    String name;
    int status;
    String message;
    int statusCode;
    String code;
    String stack;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Server's error response**

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "login failed",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "LOGIN_FAILED",
    "stack": "Error: login failed"
  }
}
```

But `errorConverter.convert()` returns an object with null values. I've looked [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519618/retrofit-2-0-how-to-get-deserialised-error-response-body), but it didn't help.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in [futurestud.io](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling#comment-2425497134) blog comments:

Changed the **APIError.java** to this:

```
public class APIError {

    Error error;

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public static class Error {

        String name;
        int status;
        String message;
        int statusCode;
        String code;
        String stack;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

    }
}
```