# Retrofit / OkHttp3 400 Error Body Empty

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit 2 in my Android project.  When I hit an API endpoint using a GET method and it returns a 400 level error I can see the error content when I use an HttpLoggingInterceptor, but when I get to the Retrofit OnResponse callback the error body's string is empty.

I can see that there is a body to the error, but I can't seem to pull that body when in the context of the Retrofit callback.  Is there a way to ensure the body is accessible there?

Thanks,
Adam

Edit:
The response I see from the server is:
{"error":{"errorMessage":"For input string: \"000001280_713870281\"","httpStatus":400}}

I am trying to pull that response from the response via:

`BaseResponse baseResponse = GsonHelper.getObject(BaseResponse.class, response.errorBody().string());
if (baseResponse != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(baseResponse.getErrorMessage()))
     error = baseResponse.getErrorMessage();`

(GsonHelper is just a helper which passes the JSON string through GSON to pull the object of type `BaseResponse`)

The call to response.errorBody().string() results in an IOException: Content-Length and stream length disagree, but I see the content literally 2 lines above in Log Cat

Comment: can you post your example code trying to access the body

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm struggling with the same issue, I can see en error response body in logs but errorBody content is empty.

Comment: I have not.  I'm just handling any error from my API in a generic sense and not showing the meaningful error to the user.  It's not ideal, but the only option I see before I understand why Retrofit / OkHttp are stripping the error info.

Comment: adamacdo, did you resolve your problem? I have the same issue.. Thank you very much

Comment: I have not.  It was for a project I have since moved on from.  I showed a generic error without the actual error from the server as a workaround.  Not helpful, but literally better than nothing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I encountered the same problem before and I fixed it by using the code **response.errorBody().string()** *only* once. You'll receive the IOException if you are using it many times so it is advised to just use it as a one-shot stream just as the Documentation on ResponseBody says.

My suggestion is: convert the Stringified errorBody() into an Object immediately as the latter is what you're gonna be using on subsequent operations.

Comment: If you need to use response.errorBody().string() more than once, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857446/9952567

Answer (score 3):

**Use the code below to get error body string from `response`. It can be used repeatedly and will not return an empty string after the first use.**

**Kotlin**:

```kotlin
fun Response<*>.getErrorBodyString(): String? {
    val peekSource = errorBody()?.source()?.peek()
    return peekSource?.let {
        val defaultCharset = errorBody()?.contentType()?.charset(UTF_8) ?: UTF_8
        val charset = it.readBomAsCharset(defaultCharset) 
        // Use the line below in older versions of okhttp
        // val charset = Util.bomAwareCharset(it, defaultCharset)
        it.readString(charset)
    }
}
```

**Java**:

```
public static String getErrorBodyString(Response<?> response) throws IOException {
    // Get a copy of error body's BufferedSource.
    BufferedSource peekSource = response.errorBody().source().peek();
    // Get the Charset, as in the original response().errorBody().string() implementation
    MediaType contentType = response.errorBody().contentType(); //
    Charset charset = contentType != null ? contentType.charset(UTF_8) : UTF_8;
    charset = Util.readBomAsCharset(peekSource, charset); 
    // Use the line below in older versions of okhttp
    // charset = Util.bomAwareCharset(peekSource, charset);
    // Read string without consuming data from the original BufferedSource.
    return peekSource.readString(charset);
}
```

And the necessary import statements:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.internal.Util;
import okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException;
import okio.BufferedSource;
import retrofit2.Response;
```

**Explanation:**
As it was mentioned, you need to use `response.errorBody().string()` only once. But there is a way to get the error body string more than once.
This is based on the original `response.errorBody().string()` method implementation. It uses the copy of `BufferedSource` from `peek()` and returns the error body string without consuming it, so you can call it as many times as you need.

If you look at the `response.errorBody().string()` method implementation, you'll see this:

```
public final String string() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedSource source = source()) {
      Charset charset = Util.bomAwareCharset(source, charset());
      return source.readString(charset);
    }
}
```

`source.readString(charset)` consumes data of the error body's `BufferedSource` instance, that's why `response.errorBody().string()` returns an empty string on next calls.

To read from error body's `BufferedSource` without consuming it we can use `peek()`, which basically returns a copy of the original `BufferedSource`:

> Returns a new BufferedSource that can read data from this
> BufferedSource without consuming it.

Comment: thank you for sharing the answer, But I have a problem with the Util.bomAwareCharset(peekSource, charset) function, Where are we getting it from? I mean from which library?

Comment: @providerZ it is from okhttp3.internal.Util.
Thanks for pointing that out, I will include it in the answer

Comment: Thank you Sir for the replay , but still Util is not exist in okhttp3.internal , maybe because of the library's version? , I tried couple of versions with negative result

Comment: @providerZ In my code Util is from com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9. I believe it is coming from this dependency: "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"

Comment: There is no `Util.bomAwareCharset`

Comment: @RomanSamoilenko use `Util.readBomAsCharset`. In newer versions of okhttp this is the new name of that method.

Comment: @RomanSamoilenko I've added it to the answer, as well as Kotlin version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gson to get errorBody as your desired model class:

```
val errorResponse: ErrorMessage? = Gson().fromJson(
                response.errorBody()!!.charStream(),
                object : TypeToken<ErrorMessage>() {}.type
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

First create an Error class like below:

```
public class ApiError {
    @SerializedName("httpStatus")
    private int statusCode;
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String message;

    public ApiError() {

    }

    public ApiError(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ApiError(int statusCode, String message) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int status() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String message() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

Second you can create a Utils class to handle your error like below:

```
public final class ErrorUtils {
    private ErrorUtils() {

    }

    public static ApiError parseApiError(Response<?> response) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ApiError> converter =
                YourApiProvider.getInstance().getRetrofit()
                        .responseBodyConverter(ApiError.class, new Annotation[0]);

        ApiError error;
        try {
            error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = new ApiError(0, "Unknown error"
        }
        return error;
    }
```

And finally handle your error like below:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
   // Your response is successfull
   callback.onSuccess();
   } 
else {
   callback.onFail(ErrorUtils.parseApiError(response));
   }
```

I hope this'll help you. Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

If you are gettig 400 then its a bad request you r trying to send to server.
check your get req.

Comment: That makes sense, but I would like to pull the error body text from the returned error to prompt to my user.  When I get a 500 level error I see there is error body text returned as well.  I would like to show any error body text regardless of the error, even if the error is due to an improperly formatted request.