# Android Retrofit Read ErrorBody.String()

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to read error message using Retrofit. I have tried errorbody.message() and errorBody().string.

Error message Postman Screenshot

[image]

Am able to print error message when use errorBody().string() but when append to Toast, its returning empty message.
Can anyone help, to fix this?

```
 println("errr,,,,,,," + response.errorBody()!!.string()) // output Middle name mst provide
                                println("errr,,,,,,," + response.errorBody()!!.toString())  //Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url="myurl"}

                                
                                Toast.makeText(context,response.errorBody()!!.string(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit / OkHttp3 400 Error Body Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383401/retrofit-okhttp3-400-error-body-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment under your post so I'm contributing this answer.

You should call `string()` on `response.errorBody()` once and store this string in another variable because `string()` will return empty string next time you call it.

```
//get error string
String error = response.errorBody().string();

//and use it
println("errr,,,,", error);
Toast.makeText(context, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629992/getting-json-from-retrofits-response-errorbody) for more info.

Comment: yeah, i did it.
its working now. Thanks for reply

Comment: If you need to use response.errorBody().string() more than once, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857446/9952567