# Retroift2 + Jackson error response handling

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I request JSON from server and normal response looks like: 
"response" : {
   "name" : "John",
   "age" : "100"
   ...
}

But for example if I don't pass access token and try to request any API method then server returns something like:
"response" : {
   "error" : "Access token is invalid"
}

How can I catch such errors with Jackson+Retrofit2?

Comment: does the server use http response codes correctly?

Comment: Yes, if token is invalid then code is 401 Not authorized

Comment: how about https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519618/retrofit-2-0-how-to-get-deserialised-error-response-body

Comment: Thanks, that's what I looked for :)