# How to Get Error Body Response with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 and I need to handle response error in JSON format. Below is the example of the response body.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": {
            "name": [
                "This input is required."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`message` contains list of fields with errors which means the value is dynamic. Therefore, one of the possible solutions is by parsing the response body as JSON Object. I tried to get the error body using `response.errorBody().string()`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final Call<Category> call, final Response<Category> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    } else {
        // Handle error
        String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, printing the `errorBody` I can only get the following result
`{"success":false,"error":{"message":{"name":[""]}}}`
Is Retrofit limiting the errorBody object depth? What should I do to get the full response body that can be parsed?

Comment: Try writing this: String errorBody = response.errorBody().string(); before else inside if true statement.

Comment: @UmangBurman Why adding `response.errorBody().string();` there? It won't go through the if true block if the response is 4xx

Comment: @NoName2 did u solve this?? I have exactly same problem.

Comment: the solution is here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70135493/4882029](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70135493/4882029) it work fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try this snippet I used this in my retrofit. and getting dynamic error messages solution

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final Call<Category> call, final Response<Category> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    } else {
        try {
            String errorBody = response.errorBody().string();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(errorBody.trim());

            jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("error");

            jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("message");

            Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
            String errors = "";
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    errors += key + " : " + arr.getString(i) + "\n";
                }
            }
            Common.errorLog("ERRORXV", errors);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: parsing the JSON object is possible. But the problem is in `response.errorBody string` I didnt get full response body object, as i havesaid on the question

Comment: `String message  =  jsonObject.getString("message");`

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get the full response if you tried response.body.toString().

Comment: try
{
String error = response.errorBody().string();
error = error.replace("\"", "");
Toast.makeText(getContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

Answer (score -2):

Just use `response.message()`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(final Call<Category> call, final Response<Category> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    } else {
        // Handle error
        Log.i("Response message: ", response.message());
    }
}
```

Comment: Printing `response.message()`, I got `Unprocessable Entity`

Comment: Yes, that is your message :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422

Comment: That's not the message. What I want is the response body

Comment: response.errorBody().string() gives the error response. response.message() does not give error message.