# How to get API error body using Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to do POST request with retrofit and coroutines,
and whenever the HTTP response status is not 200, it just throws an exception. My API has a response body that looks like this:

```
{
 "auth_token": null,
 "error": "Email can't be blank. Password can't be blank. First name can't be blank. Last name can't 
  be blank. Date of birth can't be blank"
}
```

I want to catch this error message WITHOUT CALLBACKS, is that possible ?

Api service class

```
@GET("flowers")
 suspend fun getAllFlowers(@Query("page") page: Int): Flowers

@POST("users/register")
  suspend fun registerUser(@Body user: User) : NetworkResponse
```

Network response class

```
 class NetworkResponse(
   val auth: String,
   val error:  String)
```

ViewModel class

```
     fun registerUser(user: User) {
     coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val registerUser = FlowerApi.retrofitService.registerUser(user)
            _token.value = registerUser.auth
        } catch (cause: Throwable) {
            //CATCH EXCEPTION
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2.0 how to get deserialised error response.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519618/retrofit-2-0-how-to-get-deserialised-error-response-body)

Comment: I would like to do it without callbacks is that possible? To get error body from API

Comment: do you mean you don't want to wrap request  with try catch ?

Comment: I would just like to use the best method for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `catch` block you need to check if the `throwable` is an `HttpException` (from Retrofit package) and then you can find the error body from it by calling `cause.response()?.errorBody()?.string()`:

```
catch (cause: Throwable) {
    when (cause) {
         is HttpException -> { 
              cause.response()?.errorBody()?.string() //retruns the error body
         }
         else -> {
              //Other errors like Network ...
         }
    }
}
```