# Get body From error response with Retrofit with execute()

Tags: android, retrofit2

So for some reason I need to execute my call like this:

```
val result = manager.call.execute()
if (result.isSuccess) {
   //do stuff
} else {
    //handle exeption
}
```

When my code arrives in the `else` bracket `result.body()` is null and `result.errorBody()` has its buffer content to 0 but not its length.

BUT, this are the log I get from retrofit :

```
<-- 400 Bad Request https://cubus-friends-
...
D/OkHttp: {"error":"validation_error","error_description":"No user with that phone number"}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (81-byte body)
```

How can I get my json error string into the `else` bracket in my code ?

Comment: have you tried this : [Getting JSON from RetrofitError](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21103420/1893220) ? P.S: Look at the Retrofit 2.0 part

Comment: OK so I didn't notice the Retrofit 2 section at the end of the comment... Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @florian-do, [Getting JSON from RetrofitError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21103420/1893220) contains the answer, see Retrofit2 section at the end of the answer. However, I'm using kotlin and this little change is necessary to obtain the converter :

```
val a = object : Annotation{}
val converter = Backend.retrofit. //this is for accessing my Retrofit object
        responseBodyConverter<Error>(Error::class.java, arrayOf(a))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a simple class like this

```
class ApiError constructor(error: Throwable) {
    var errorMessage = "An error occurred"
    var error = "error"

    init {
        if (error is HttpException) {
            val errorJsonString = error.response()
                                       .errorBody()?.string()
            parsedString = JsonParser().parse(errorJsonString)
            this.error = parsedString.asJsonObject["error"].asString
            this.errorMessage = parsedString.asJsonObject["error_message"].asString
        } else {
            this.errorMessage = error.message ?: this.errorMessage
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like so

```
try  { 
    val result = manager.call.execute()
} catch(error: IOException) {
    ApiError(error).errorMessage
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can use `ApiError(error).errorMessage` anywhere in your code without having to rewrite the parsing logic.

This is all from [this blog post](https://chunksofco.de/getting-json-body-from-retrofit-error-kotlin-6a2281875503) (which I wrote).

Answer (score 1):

This is best way without creating unused annotation object instance

```
responseBodyConverter<Error>(Error::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data when error response comes (typically a response code except 200) you can do it like that in your onResponse() method:

```
  if (result.isSuccess) {
  //do stuff
  } else {
  //handle exeption
      val converter = 
      ApiClient.getClient()?.responseBodyConverter<ErrorResponseData>(
                ErrorResponseData::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
                        var errorResponse: ErrorResponseData? = null
                            errorResponse = converter?.convert(response.errorBody())
                            if (errorResponse != null) {
                                //TODO: Handle Error case...
                            }
  }
```